# WebRTC Screensharing in electron

Tags: webrtc, electron, janus-gateway

We have a web app to which I'm building electron app by loading URL in browserWindow. But when i try to share the screen it will give me a popup saying Please install the  janus webRTC screen sharing plugin and restart the browser. Please help !

Comment: So, the fact that you use (also) electron is irrelevant here, right? It would also help if you clarify that the URL is a janus based web app...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to implement your own desktop picker dialog in electron. See [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4432)

Comment: My issue was with sharing screen from web app not do it on electron. But I got another idea after going through the link you shared. Thank you.

Comment: @SumukhaAithalK how you implemented screen sharing please share your code. when i tried to share the screen the other end is receiving my video call I am stuck this. Any help is appreciated.