# getDisplayMedia() is not available in webview of Electron

Tags: electron, webrtc

[image]

I already have a webrtc site.

And I want to open the site from iframe or webview of the electronic.

However, when the getDisplayMedia() function is called on the site, the permission is automatically denied because a pop-up window does not appear to select the screen.

Is there a good way?

The screen below doesn't show

[image]

Comment: Most likely you need to do your own picker dialog, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685507/webrtc-screensharing-in-electron

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebRTC Screensharing in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685507/webrtc-screensharing-in-electron)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so. I want to solve it by manipulating the site in iframe, not inside the electron. thanks!